# Edit Windows 8 Boot Menu from XP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8

I have a computer running windows xp with a failed installation attempt to Windows 8. Apparently my hardware does not support windows 8 and I want to revert back to XP.

When I boot up my computer, I now get a menu with two options: Windows Setup and Earlier Versions of Windows. If I pick "Earlier versions of windows", my XP instance starts up successfully. However, I only get 2 seconds to make a decision between the different options.

I looked in my XP's boot.ini file and there is no mention of Windows Setup or "Earlier Versions of Windows". The XP boot.ini file only shows XP.

Where do I go in XP to disable the Windows 8 boot menu or make it default to "Earlier Versions of Windows" instead of Windows Setup. Note that my Windows 8 does not start so I can't use bcedit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/repairmbr.htm

It will completely remove the Windows 8 bootloader and revert you back to just the XP one with NTLDR, boot.ini and NTDETECT.COM.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works, you can also grab a Linux Live CD / USB stick and install grub as your main bootloader. It should recognize your windows partitions automatically and set the entries accordingly. You could then delete the Windows 8 entry and set the timeout to 0 seconds.

You can use grub as your boot loader regardless of your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried MSCONFIG?

`WinKey` + `r`, Run MSCONFIG

Select the Boot tab. Adjust the timeout.  Also you could delete the Windows 8 option if you wished.